# MKMapView NSInvalidArgumentException Invalid Region crash in ios6

Tags: ios6, mkmapview

Program crashes when set location coordinates using MKMapView.
Log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region `<center:+112.57075000, +37.87049600 span:+0.05165163, +0.43945312>`'

span in my program is

```
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = .05;
span.longitudeDelta = .02;
```

after coding:

```
    self.mMKMapview.region = [self.mMKMapview regionThatFits:region];
```

as the log shows, span changes to :+0.05165163, +0.43945312

anyone help please, I have been standstill here for two days.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is the `center` coordinate:

> +112.57075000, +37.87049600

The latitude must be from -90 to +90 so +112.57075 is out of range.

Check how the center coordinate is being set or maybe the data is backwards.

Also, you don't need to explicitly call `regionThatFits` because the map view does it automatically when you set the region normally (ie. just call `setRegion`).  It's normal, by the way, for the map view to adjust the span as needed to fit the map view dimensions or zoom level.

Answer (score 4):

I would rather suggest to use [CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/1423806-cllocationcoordinate2disvalid)

so something like

```
guard CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(centerLat) else {

     return
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code to set the region:

```
if( centerLat > -89 && centerLat < 89 && centerLng > -179 && centerLng < 179 ){
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```